# How to reduce complexity of function using multiple if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, logic, list-comprehension

I have written this function for a game I am making, however I feel like I have overcomplicated thinks by using multiple nested if statements. Does anyone know a more concise way of doing this? I'm fairly new to coding so apologies if this seems trivial.

The function checks the following:

**Team == 0**: the row - previousrow is a negative value

**Team == 1**: the row - previousrow is a positive value

```
def check(item, row, col):
    previousRow = 6 
    if item.team == 0:
        if ((row - previousRow) < 0):
            return False
        else:
            return True
    else:
        if item.team == 1:
            if ((row - previousRow) > 0):
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

Comment: Check out [Sourcery](https://sourcery.ai/) for help with refactoring code.

Comment: Thank you will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `item.team` is neither 0 not 1, then your code falls through and executes no explicit `return` statement, which is the equivalent of returning `None`. But if you are sure that `item.team` will always be 0 or 1, then the second test for 1 when the first test for 0 has failed becomes unnecessary.

So under the assumption that `item.team` will always be 0 or 1, the code can be simplified to:

```
def check(item, row, col):
    previousRow = 6 
    return row - previous >= 0 if item.team == 0 else row - previousRow <= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [Sourcery](https://sourcery.ai/) reduces your code to:

```
def check(item, row, col):
    previousRow = 6
    if item.team == 0:
        return row - previousRow >= 0
    elif item.team == 1:
        return row - previousRow <= 0
```